# Undefined class 'StorageReference'. while uploading image in firebase using flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

**Undefined class 'StorageReference'. while uploading image in firebase using flutter **

[image: Undefined class 'StorageReference'. while uploading image in firebase using flutter]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this changelog](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_storage/firebase_storage/CHANGELOG.md#500-dev1), `StorageReference` has been renamed to `Reference` since `5.0.0-dev.1`

Perform the change accordingly, also go through the changelog as there are some other breaking changes as well